# how to toggle comments component via onClick function ,react js

Tags: arrays, reactjs, components, toggle, map-function

```js
import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { getPosts } from '../redux/actions/@posts';
import PostItem from '../components/posts/PostItem';
import CommentForm from '../components/posts/CommentForm';
import Comment from '../components/posts/Comment';
import '../styles/posts/postComponent.scss';

const Posts = ({
  getPosts,
  posts: { posts, isLoading },
  isAuthenticated,
  user
}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getPosts();
  }, []);
  const [show, toggleShow] = useState(false);
  console.log(show);
  const postsList = isLoading ? (
    <div>posts are loading</div>
  ) : (
    posts.map(post => {
      return (
        <div className='post'>
          <PostItem
            key={post._id}
            auth={isAuthenticated}
            user={user}
            id={post._id}
            title={post.title}
            body={post.text}
            author={post.name}
            avatar={post.avatar}
            date={post.date}
            likes={post.likes}
            comments={post.comments.map(comment => comment)}
            toggleShow={toggleShow}
            show={show}
          />
          <CommentForm id={post._id} />
          {post.comments.map(
            comment =>
              show && (
                <Comment
                  key={comment._id}
                  comment={comment}
                  auth={isAuthenticated}
                  admin={user}
                  show={show}
                />
              )
          )}
        </div>
      );
    })
  );
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Link to='/add-post'>add Post</Link>
      <div>{postsList}</div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

Posts.propTypes = {
  getPosts: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  posts: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  // console.log(state.posts.posts.map(post => post.likes));
  // console.log(state);

  return {
    posts: state.posts,
    isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated,
    user: state.auth.user
  };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getPosts })(Posts);
```

```js
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import '../../styles/posts/postComponent.scss';

const Comment = ({
  comment: { user, avatar, name, date, text },
  admin,
  auth
}) => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className='c-container'>
        <div className='c-img-text'>
          <img className='c-img' height={'40px'} src={avatar} />
          <div className='c-nt'>
            <a href='#' className='c-n'>
              {name}
            </a>
            <span className='c-t'> {text}</span>
            <i className='c-d'>{date}</i>
          </div>
          {auth && admin
            ? admin._id === user && <div className='c-toggle'>...</div>
            : ''}
        </div>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Comment;
```

I have a list of posts stored in redux, and mapped through it to create components. Now each component has a some body  and comments.
I want to show the comments only after onClick event . 
Below is the code I have come up with , and on Click it is toggling all the comments of all the Components.How can I toggle comments  of an individual Component.

Comment: please provide code that you tried

Comment: please provide the code so that people will understand your problem better and will be easy for them to help you out...your statements are not concise enough to provide you the solution

Comment: using one show var, to toggle is causing your issue, i see you console.log your show, so check its state and all your compnents state as you click on one component and i belive you will see all your other compnents show change state as well

Comment: yes ,that is happening exactly.

Comment: so I added a show state in  each Comment.

Comment: in order to trigger it the show state should be passed to other component, how do I do so?